# How do I use html decode in my view page?

Tags: asp.net, html, c#-3.0, html-encode

My engine is Aspx.

I am currently having trouble editing one of my columns(Question Answer) in my table because it has html tags in it. Is there a way I can decode only that specific row/column in the value area?

```
<form id="updateFreqQuestionsUser" action="<%=Url.Action("SaveFreqQuestionsUser","Prod")%>" method="post">
<table> 
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="tableHeader">Freq Questions User Details <input type ="hidden" value="<%=freqQuestionsUser.freqQuestionsUserId%>" name="freqQuestionsUserId"/> </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="label">Question Description:</td>
        <td class="content">
            <input type="text" maxlength="2000" name="QuestionDescription" value="<%=freqQuestionsUser.questionDescription%>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="label">QuestionAnswer:</td>
        <td class="content">
            <input type="text" maxlength="2000" name="QuestionAnswer" value="<%=freqQuestionsUser.questionAnswer%>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="tableFooter">
                <br />
                <a id="freqQuestionsUserUpdateButton" href="#" class="regularButton">Save</a>
                <a href="javascript:history.back()" class="regularButton">Cancel</a>
        </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="2000" name="QuestionAnswer" 
value="<%=Server.HtmlDecode(freqQuestionsUser.questionAnswer)%>" />
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx)

Comment: I tried that an when i tried to edit. I put name <br/> yusuf <br/> phone<br/> 814-274-6484 then it gave me this error

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (QuestionAnswer="...ics Phone:<br/>814-274-6484 <b...")

Comment: That's completely normal. ASP.NET is validating against possible XSS attacks. If you need to submit this field back to the server, you'd have to encode it into something different that doesn't have any HTML markup. You can use base64 encoding, for example, but it will require a jquery plugin if you want to be able to support all browsers.

Comment: okay. I am connecting back to a server. i will google base64 encoding